# how to round my answer

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following, but I need the answer in percentage and I keep getting 0. I was wondering how to round my answer. Thanks in advance!

```
SELECT (COUNT(t1.[ENTRY CODE])/2948) AS 'SecondYearRetention'

FROM 
        t1

Inner join
        t2 ON t1.CLID = t2.CLID

WHERE t1.[ENTRY CODE] = 'FTF' OR t1.[ENTRY CODE] = 'CFTF'
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `2948.0` instead of `2948`:

```
SELECT 
  (COUNT(t1.[ENTRY CODE]) / 2948.0) AS 'SecondYearRetention'
FROM  t1
Inner join t2 ON t1.CLID = t2.CLID
WHERE t1.[ENTRY CODE] = 'FTF' OR t1.[ENTRY CODE] = 'CFTF'
```

Comment: it worked, but I got 7 decimals. How can I make it 3 decimals? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @user2134610 - You're welcome :) Use [`ROUND`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175003.aspx) with the precession you want. Like `ROUND((COUNT(t1.[ENTRY CODE]) / 2948.0), 3)` [**See it in action here**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/11278)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ROUND((COUNT(t1.[ENTRY CODE])/2948),3)AS 'SecondYearRetention'

FROM 
        t1

Inner join
        t2 ON t1.CLID = t2.CLID

WHERE t1.[ENTRY CODE] = 'FTF' OR t1.[ENTRY CODE] = 'CFTF'
```

Try this for more result  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175003.aspx

Comment: This example will give you 0, because dividing two integer numbers give integer, and ROUND() function do nothing

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use [CAST or CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226054%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) functions with data_type which is necessary for you

```
SELECT 
  (CAST(COUNT(t1.[ENTRY CODE]) AS decimal(9,8)) / 2948) AS 'SecondYearRetention'
FROM  t1
Inner join t2 ON t1.CLID = t2.CLID
WHERE t1.[ENTRY CODE] = 'FTF' OR t1.[ENTRY CODE] = 'CFTF'
```

OR

```
SELECT 
  (CONVERT(decimal(9,8),COUNT(t1.[ENTRY CODE])) / 2948) AS 'SecondYearRetention'
FROM  t1
Inner join t2 ON t1.CLID = t2.CLID
WHERE t1.[ENTRY CODE] = 'FTF' OR t1.[ENTRY CODE] = 'CFTF'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
SELECT ROUND(CAST(COUNT(t1.[ENTRY CODE]) AS FLOAT) / 2948),3) AS 'SecondYearRetention'

FROM 
        t1

Inner join
        t2 ON t1.CLID = t2.CLID

WHERE t1.[ENTRY CODE] = 'FTF' OR t1.[ENTRY CODE] = 'CFTF'
```